# apache mod_jk.so start up Permission denied

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, mod-jk, ajp

I am trying to configure mod_jk in Apache 2.2.3 to connect with Tomcat 7. OS is CentOS 5

After all the configuration, while starting the Apache httpd I am getting -

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 200 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

I see the permission is set alright

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  266752 Jun  3 19:37 mod_jk.so
```

I don't know what to do. Can any one please help?

Comment: copy paste line 200 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: I don't understand the combination of "while starting Tomcat 7" and "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf": Does your tomcat read httpd.conf? It must be a message from Apache httpd, right? As that's typically starting as root, permissions should be good. If it already dropped the permissions, make sure that the *directory* `/etc/httpd/modules` (and its parents) are readable for the unprivileged apache user, whichever CentOS uses.

Comment: @Olaf I edited the question.  It's not tomcat 7,  it's apache.

Comment: @Olaf I am using the Root only.  I am totally using root from the beginning of configuration.

Comment: @Ghayel, here is the content of line 200: LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

Comment: #Comment line 200 and `service httpd restart`

Comment: Yes it's working fine.

Comment: I don't think I did any mistakes in configuration. I don't if it's a problem that I am using binary instead of building the mod_jk from source.

Comment: I tried building from source and it worked. But still confused why the binaries were not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check your SELinux configuration.

Either open file /etc/selinux/config and check selinux setting or

run `getenforce` and see the output.

If I am correct then you will find it to be `Enforcing`. Now set it to permissive and restart httpd. You might need to reboot system to take effect.